# Neo4J: Match all nodes with relation that has specific attribute value?

Tags: attributes, neo4j, cypher, relation

I need to find *all* nodes connected with relation that has attribute `fld = email`. Neo4j Cypher complains the following as a query with bad syntax:

```
MATCH (n)-[r:rel*..]-(m) WHERE has(r.fld) and r.fld='email' RETURN n,r,m
```

What would be the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best bet:

```
MATCH (n)-[r:rel {fld: 'email'}]-(m) RETURN n, r, m;
```

This should match nodes that are connected with a "rel" relationship that has a property "fld" with the value "email".

HTH